# memory leak probably due to recursive function

Tags: c++, matlab, recursion, mex

I have an implementation of random forest in c++, which I am running in matlab through mex. It runs smoothly till it reaches the function below, where it gets stuck and starts consuming memory till the computer freezes.

```
void MyFunction(
  const IDataPointCollection& data,
  std::vector<std::vector<int> >& leafNodeIndices,
  ProgressStream* progress=0 ) const
{
  ProgressStream defaultProgressStream(std::cout, Interest);
  progress = (progress==0)?&defaultProgressStream:progress;

  leafNodeIndices.resize(TreeCount());

  tbb::parallel_for<int>(0,TreeCount(),[&](int t)
  {
    leafNodeIndices[t].resize(data.Count());

    (*progress)[Interest] << "\rApplying tree " << t << "...";
    trees_[t]->Apply(data, leafNodeIndices[t]);
  });
  (*progress)[Interest] << "STUCK HERE" << std::endl;
  return;
}
```

Going through the code for `trees_[t]->Apply()` above, I was able to narrow it down to the recursive function below:

```
void ApplyNode(
  int nodeIndex,
  const IDataPointCollection& data,
  std::vector<unsigned int>& dataIndices,
  int i0,
  int i1,
  std::vector<int>& leafNodeIndices,
  std::vector<float>& responses_)
{
std::cout<<"applying node"<<std::endl;
  assert(nodes_[nodeIndex].IsNull()==false);

  Node<F,S>& node = nodes_[nodeIndex];

  if (node.IsLeaf())
  {
    for (int i = i0; i < i1; i++)
      leafNodeIndices[dataIndices[i]] = nodeIndex;
    return;
  }

  else if (i0 == i1)   // No samples left
    return;

  else 
  {
        for (int i = i0; i < i1; i++)
            responses_[i] = node.Feature.GetResponse(data, dataIndices[i]);

        int ii = Partition(responses_, dataIndices, i0, i1, node.Threshold);

        // Recurse for child nodes.
        ApplyNode(nodeIndex * 2 + 1, data, dataIndices, i0, ii, leafNodeIndices, responses_);
        ApplyNode(nodeIndex * 2 + 2, data, dataIndices, ii, i1, leafNodeIndices, responses_);
        return;
  }
    }
```

Each call to the recursive function has different computation time depending on `node.Feature.GetResponse()` function. If I make the computation time same for all recursive calls (by changing `GetResponse()`), the code runs smoothly.

```
    float AxisAlignedFeatureResponse::GetResponse(const IDataPointCollection& data, int index) const {

    double retArg;
    // retrieve DataManager object
    const DataManager& concreteData = (const DataManager&)(data);

//     // retrieve data point at index 
    DataPoint currDataPoint         = concreteData.getDataPoint(index);
//     
//     // get coordinates of data point
    Coordinate currCoordinates      = currDataPoint.getOrigPos();
//     
//     // get intensity image of the respective data point
    int imgIndex    = currDataPoint.getImageIndex();  
    Image currImg   = concreteData.getImage(imgIndex);    
    Image currFeatureImg = concreteData.getFeatureImage(imgIndex);
    // return respective feature
    int featureNumber = (int)(this->axis*(double)concreteData.getNumberOfFeatures());    
    if(featureNumber>=concreteData.getNumberOfFeatures()){
        cout<<"warning! trying to reach a feature that is not there!"<<endl;
        featureNumber=concreteData.getNumberOfFeatures()-1;
    }

    std::vector<Coordinate> feature = concreteData.getFeature(featureNumber);
    Coordinate tmp=currCoordinates+feature[0];
    if(feature[1].x == 0) {
        retArg = currCoordinates.x*feature[0].x+currCoordinates.y*feature[0].y+currCoordinates.z*feature[0].z;
    //retArg = 0;      //DOING THIS runs the code smoothly
    } 

    else if(feature[1].x == 2) {
       retArg = currFeatureImg.getValue(feature[0]);
    } else {
        retArg = currImg.mean(tmp,feature[1]);
    }
    return (float)(retArg);   
        //return (float) 0;
}
```

Comment: So wouldn't it seem likely the problem is in GetResponse?  Where is the code for that?

Comment: @xaxxon added now, though i don't see how there can be a problem in that except for difference in computation time

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). I can't see any cause for a memory leak unless your program is terminating abruptly. Memory leaks are usually caused by heap variables not being freed ("new" not being followed by a later "delete").

Valgrind will give you a culprit and line number, and you can set breakpoints and step through with gdb to see what exactly is going on. Maybe post the detailed output of running "valgrind -v your_program". Don't forget to compile with the -g option to provide full debugging data to valgrind and gdb.

Comment: unfortunately there is no documented way to run valgrind with matlab mex files